# Localize strftime in Javascript

Tags: javascript, internationalization, strftime

I wanted to have day names and month names be localized using strftime in Javascript.

```js
"le %A %e %B à %-Hh%M" // for french
"%A %e %B at %l:%M%p" // for english
```

Answer (score 0):

Using https://github.com/samsonjs/strftime you can add locales

```
let fr = {
  days: ["dimanche", "lundi", "mardi", "mercredi", "jeudi", "vendredi", "samedi"],
  months: ["janvier", "février", "mars", "avril", "mai", "juin", "juillet", "aout", "septembre", "octobre", "novembre", "décembre"]
}

let strftimeFR = strftime.localize(fr)
strftimeFR("le %A %e %B à %-Hh%M")
```

or even simpler:

```js
let strftimeFR = strftime.localizeByIdentifier("fr_FR")
strftimeFR("le %A %e %B à %-Hh%M")
```